# PROGRAMA EN C# "INSERTAR INFORMACION EN UN DATAGRIDVIEW Y ACTUALIZAR EXCEL"

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, .net

Tengo mi programa el cual tiene una ruta definida donde se guardar reportes semanales en excel con un formato dado. Mi sistema crea el mismo formato tomando 6 columnas.

Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Comentarios.

El objetivo es que en mi programa cuando escriba un comentario en cada fila, y cuando le de CTRL + S o a un botón de guardar, se actualice el archivo con el que estoy trabajando.

Proceso:

Abro el programa
Corro el programa
Selecciono un reporte (los reportes llevan un nombre con la fecha del día de creación)
Veo el registro (row) al que voy a escribirle un comentario
Ya sea un botón o un CTRL + S que se guarde ese comentario
La primer columna funciona como ID ya que son registros de facturas

Al final quiero que cuando me llegue un nuevo reporte ya sea del día 11 de marzo de 2024 y si viene la misma factura (hay veces que se paga y ya no aparece la factura en el nuevo reporte(, en el caso de que si venga la misma factura que se actualice el reporte nuevo con el viejo y traiga el comentario.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using OfficeOpenXml;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    namespace GRNIApp
    {
    public partial class Interfaz : Form
    {
        private EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> rows;
        private readonly string predefinedPath = @"C:\Users\c-avalenzuela\OneDrive - All\Desktop\GRNI 2024";  // Define tu ruta predefinida aquí

        public Interfaz()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillComboBoxWithExcelFiles();
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial; // o LicenseContext.Commercial dependiendo de tu uso

        }


        private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void FillComboBoxWithExcelFiles()
        {
            var excelFiles = Directory.GetFiles(predefinedPath, "*.xlsx");
            foreach (var file in excelFiles)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
            }
        }
        private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedFile = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedFile))
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(predefinedPath, selectedFile);
                OpenExcelFile(filePath);
            }
        }
        private void OpenExcelFile(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
                {
                    // Obtén la primera hoja de cálculo en el libro de trabajo
                    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

                    // Convierte la hoja de cálculo en un DataTable
                    var dataTable = WorksheetToDataTable(worksheet);

                    // Asigna el DataTable al DataSource del DataGridView
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

                    // Convierte el DataTable a una lista de filas para poder usar LINQ
                    rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable();

                    // Añade los elementos a tu CheckedListBox
                    var sites = rows.Select(row => row.Field<string>("Site")).Distinct();
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Clear(); // Limpia los elementos existentes
                    foreach (var site in sites)
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(site);
                    }

                    // Marca todos los elementos por defecto
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Muestra el mensaje de error en una ventana de mensaje, o maneja el error de la manera que prefieras
                MessageBox.Show($"Se produjo un error al abrir el archivo: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }



        private DataTable WorksheetToDataTable(ExcelWorksheet ws)
        {
            try
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                if (ws.Dimension == null)  // Verifica si la hoja de cálculo está vacía
                {
                    return dt;  // Retorna un DataTable vacío
                }

                // Encuentra la primera fila que contiene datos
                int startRow = 1;
                while (ws.Cells[startRow, 1].Value == null || ws.Cells[startRow, 1].Value.ToString() == "")
                {
                    startRow++;
                }

                // Usa la primera fila que contiene datos como los encabezados de las columnas
                foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[startRow, 1, startRow, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
                }

                // Lee las filas de datos
                for (int rowNum = startRow + 1; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                {
                    var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                    {
                        int columnIndex = cell.Start.Column - 1;
                        if (columnIndex >= 0 && columnIndex < dt.Columns.Count)
                        {
                            row[columnIndex] = cell.Text;
                        }
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                // Hace que los valores en la columna "sum of net accrual balance" sean positivos
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    // Asegúrate de que el valor no sea null antes de intentar convertirlo
                    if (decimal.TryParse(row["sum of net accrual balance"].ToString(), out decimal number))
                    {
                        row["sum of net accrual balance"] = Math.Abs(number);
                    }
                }

                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Muestra el mensaje de error en una ventana de mensaje, o maneja el error de la manera que prefieras
                MessageBox.Show($"Se produjo un error al abrir el archivo: {ex.Message}");
                return null;  // Retorna null si se produce una excepción
            }
        }


        private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Verifica si la celda editada está en la columna de comentarios
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Comentarios")
            {
                // Obtiene el nuevo comentario
                var newComment = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

                // Convierte EnumerableRowCollection a List
                List<DataRow> rowsList = rows.ToList();

                // Obtiene el nombre del archivo Excel correspondiente a la fila editada
                var fileName = rowsList[e.RowIndex].Field<string>("FileName"); // Asegúrate de que tienes una columna "FileName" en tu DataTable

                // Abre el archivo Excel y actualiza el comentario
                var filePath = Path.Combine(predefinedPath, fileName);
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
                {
                    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0]; // Asume que los datos están en la primera hoja
                    worksheet.Cells[e.RowIndex + 2, e.ColumnIndex + 1].Value = newComment; // Asume que los datos comienzan en la segunda fila y segunda columna
                    package.Save();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck_1(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            // Obtiene el sitio que se está marcando o desmarcando
            var site = checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString().Trim().ToLower();

            // Dependiendo del nuevo estado del elemento, filtra las filas
            if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                // Si el sitio está siendo marcado, muestra las filas correspondientes
                dataGridView1.DataSource = rows.Where(row => row.Field<string>("Site").Trim().ToLower() == site).CopyToDataTable();
            }
            else
            {
                // Si el sitio está siendo desmarcado, oculta las filas correspondientes
                var filteredRows = rows.Where(row => row.Field<string>("Site").Trim().ToLower() != site).CopyToDataTable();

                // Verifica si todas las casillas están desmarcadas
                if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 1) // Solo queda 1 porque aún no se ha actualizado el estado del elemento que se está desmarcando
                {
                    // Si todas las casillas están desmarcadas, limpia la tabla
                    filteredRows.Clear();
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = filteredRows;
            }
        }

        private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);

            if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S) // Verifica si se presionó Control + S
            {
                SaveToExcel();
            }
        }

        private void SaveToExcel()
        {
            // Convierte EnumerableRowCollection a List
            List<DataRow> rowsList = rows.ToList();

            // Obtiene el nombre del archivo Excel correspondiente a la fila editada
            var fileName = rowsList[0].Field<string>("FileName"); // Asegúrate de que tienes una columna "FileName" en tu DataTable

            // Abre el archivo Excel y guarda los cambios
            var filePath = Path.Combine(predefinedPath, fileName);
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0]; // Asume que los datos están en la primera hoja

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value; // Asume que los datos comienzan en la segunda fila y segunda columna
                    }
                }

                package.Save();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema???